# Неправильное построение кубов

Tags: java

**Задача**:  построить здание, в котором будет куча из n кубов. Куб внизу будет иметь объем n ^ 3, куб выше будет иметь объем (n-1) ^ 3 и так далее до тех пор, пока верх не будет иметь объем 1 ^ 3.

Вам дан общий объем здания. Получив m, вы можете найти количество n кубов, которые вам нужно будет построить?

Параметр функции findNb (find_nb, find-nb, findNb) будет целым числом m, и вы должны вернуть целое число n, например n ^ 3 + (n-1) ^ 3 + ... + 1 ^ 3 = m, если такой существует, или -1, если такого нет.

**Проблема**: у меня не проходит два теста, вот код:

```
public static long findNb(long M) {
    long m = 0;
    long i = 0;
    while (m < M) {
        m += Math.pow(i, 3);
        if (m == M) {
            return i;
            }
        i += 1;
        }
    return -1;
}
```

Тесты, которые не проходит:

```
Первый:
    expected:<55100> but was:<-1>
Второй:
    Find n of : 2070953479852762176
    expected:<53648> but was:<-1>
```

Comment: *Вам дан общий объем здания* А что это в данном случае? если Вы полагаете, что тупо сумма объёмов кубов, то к этому в условии нет никаких предпосылок.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте умножение вместо [`Math.pow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow-double-double-):

```
m += i*i*i;
```

`pow` возвращает `double`, а числа с плавающей точкой расчитываются с погрешностью, что и приводит к ошибке.

Вот первый шаг вычислений, который приводит к ошибке:

```
//сумма до 13776
long s = 9005246260992576L; 
//номер следующего куба
long n = 13777;
//с Math.pow получается 9007861214521008
System.out.println((long) (s+Math.pow(13777, 3)));
//с умножением          9007861214521009
System.out.println(s+n*n*n);
```